# Poor performance with Virtual Box on MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, virtualization, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 via Virtual Box on my MacBook Pro 2017 w/ TouchBar (3.3Ghz i7, 16 GB 2133 MHZ) and I am getting a very laggy and unpleasant experience on the machine. I have gone through the suggested changes from 7 years ago here:  https://superuser.com/questions/172989/virtualbox-running-ubuntu-is-slow-mac-os-x-host

But it does not seem to make a difference. Even when I change the resolution to 720p the performance is still quite poor. Here are the settings for the vm:

```
 <Hardware>
  <CPU>
    <PAE enabled="true"/>
    <LongMode enabled="true"/>
    <X2APIC enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
  </CPU>
  <Memory RAMSize="8192"/>
  <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
  <Chipset type="ICH9"/>
  <Display VRAMSize="128"/>
  <VideoCapture fps="25" options="ac_enabled=false"/>
  <RemoteDisplay>
    <VRDEProperties>
      <Property name="TCP/Ports" value="3389"/>
    </VRDEProperties>
  </RemoteDisplay>
  <BIOS>
    <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
  </BIOS>
  <USB>
    <Controllers>
      <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
    </Controllers>
  </USB>
  <StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
```

Any thoughts on the settings? I feel like I should be able to get some decent performance out of this machine. (I have tried smaller RAMsizes with no success either). Alternative solutions if this a common Virtual Box issue?

Comment: I'd contact VirtualBox support. This sounds like an incompatibility issue or a settings issue.

Comment: Have you tried installing the guest additions?

Comment: @DavidAnderson yea just tried but no luck. Reinstalled VBox and downloaded a the iso again but no luck

Comment: There is always the option to not use virtualbox and use a dual boot.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Seems like a lot of issues with dual booting ubuntu on the newer MacBooks https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7 https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux

Comment: Out of curiosity...why are using an IDE controller and using the host controller IOCache?  Why not SATA and identify the drive as an SSD (to VB)?

Comment: @Allan this just illustrates my inexperience tbh, these are the defaults. I didn't notice an issue with writes/reads though, just happens to be visual delays so I didn't think to experiment with the storage controller

Comment: Decided to downgrade Virtual Box to 5.0.30 and performance increased dramatically. For posterity, I decided to do this after reading this thread: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=81247&start=30

Comment: GUI or CLI? GUI requires hardware accel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Retina itself. If you use other monitor with other resolution (no retina) you'll see much better performance.
I think it's an issue with OSX and Retina/HiDPI Resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the second monitor for VM definitely will improve performance.

Another workaround could be using a remote connection to VM.

I installed [XRDP](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/) on Ubuntu VM on my MBP and using RDP client for access, no issues with performance.

Please check this [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=90446&sid=391cad0521a6d2ce5848c78a38033893&start=45). There is another suggestion to use tool for Mac to use an additional range of screen resolution, so your VM instance can run smoothly on retina display

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is very old post, but just in case anyone still wondering how to fix/solve this issue...

The problem is on Mac's Retina display, as @Rubén Gómez García stated.

The fix(ish) for this problem is:

Firstly, make scale factor to 100%. This is MUST.

Then, in the Finder, go to Applications -> VirtualBox.app and choose Show Package Contents from the Finder context menu to see the contents of the app package. Continue to go to Contents -> Resources -> VirtualBoxVM.app.

Once you found VirtualBoxVm.app, then open context menu to get to the properties of VirtualBoxVM.app.

Then, under General, there is a checkbox called "Open in Low Resolution", you can disable HiDPI display by checking this. Don't worry, you won't notice the difference between HiDPI vs. Low Res. At least I didn't.

In my environment (Macbook Pro 13inch 2020 with 32GB RAM, Core i7 + Big sur 11.5.2), the performance was greatly improved by doing this setting, so I will leave it here as a reminder.

Feel free to correct/improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as well with Big Sur + Vbox 6.1.26

Comment: @joonasj Hey, thanks for feedback! I wasn't sure if it would works for everyone, but I was relieved to hear that it's working fine.